# Adsense top anchor ad vs fixed Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

if i have fixed Navbar on the site, the Adsense appears over the top bar which is incorrect, if i have position relative the anchor ad appears above it, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Adsense has given a code to disable anchor ad from the top of your website and display it at the bottom. However, this code did not work for me.

from [Disable anchor ads at the top of your page](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7478225?hl=en)

Example

> ```
> <head>
> <script async 
> src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js? 
> client=ca-pub-1234567890123456" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script>
>   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
>     google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1234567890123456",
>     enable_page_level_ads: true,
>     overlays: {bottom: true}
>   });
> </script>
> </head>
> ```

Note: If you're using the AdSense code, you'll need to replace your ad code with the old Auto ads code shown in this example.